Get the specific value from array list based on the key value in Javascript
I have an array of below type,
[{
  "type":"G",
  "amount":"123",
  "penamount":"110"
},{
  "type":"N",
  "amount":"123",
  "penamount":"123"
},{
  "type":"B",
  "amount":"1000",
  "penamount":"900"
}]

Now in case if I need the amount for type "N" how can I easy achieve this in javascript.Using map is one option.But how can that be achieved
Any help appreciated.

Since you're looking for a single amount, map() is probably not the best choice, since it returns a value for each item in the array. I would start with Array.find()

As an alternative, you can use the filter method, such as : console.log(arr.filter(e => e.type=== 'N')[0].amount);
